# How to set a different textview for different columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have  a java class that is retriving two columns from a database in android sqllite. Is it possible to set different textviews layout properties to the two columns? If yes, I would wish to know the way to go.

This is what i have done so far.

my textview layout properties

```
<----Main Title---->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/firstLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Subtitle-->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/firstLine"
android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
android:textSize="12sp"
 />
```

This is the method for quering our the data from the database

```
    /**
     * DISPLAY RESULTS
     */

    //Create Cursor object to read notification from the table
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID,NOTIFICATIONS FROM notices order by ID desc", null);

    //If Cursor is valid
    if (c != null ) {
        Toast.makeText(Notification.this, "Query is valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Move cursor to first row
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String Name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NOTIFICATIONS"));

               int Ids = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));

                //Add the notification to Arraylist 'results'
                results.add(Name);


            }while (c.moveToNext()); //Move to next row
        }
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.notification_textview,R.id.firstLine, results);


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In this case, I would want the `firstLine` textview properties be set for the `Name` column and the `secondLine` textview properties be set for the `Ids` colums.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty easy.

Create a custom layout XML file representing each row of the list view in `res/layout` folder. Let's call it `list_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24px" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="16px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see there are two TextView s in it, with IDs `text1` and `text2`
Now instead of the ArrayAdapter which is only for extremely simple lists, we use a `SimpleAdapter`

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list_row, new String[] { "text1", "text2" },
 new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 });
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now here's the tricky part. the variable data is actually an ArrayList of Map objects, and each of those maps should have entries with key "text1" and "text2". It can be created like this:

```
data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>;

for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put("text1", mainTitles.get(i));
    hm.put("text2", subtitles.get(i));
    data.add(hm);
}
```

assuming that all first lines are stored in the List `mainTitles` and second lines in list `subtitles`